# How to save the “chunks” of a http response?

Tags: bash, http

I'd like to save the "chunks" of an http response, preferably using curl or some other free command line tool that works on mac or linux, but I'm open to any type of solution.

So for example, if a response is being sent in 10 chunks, I'd like to save each one of those chunks to a separate file, `chunk1.txt` -> `chunk10.txt`

And of course if a file is being sent in a single chunk, then the file would be saved to a single file.

**How can I make save the chunks of an http response using curl or some other tool?**

EDIT: I'd like to "see" this to verify that `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is serving 1-N chunks, and `Content-Length:XXX` is sending a single response. And saving them to a file isn't neccessary, I guess. If it's clearly noted in a single file what each chunk is, that's great!

Comment: If Transfer-Encoding is not set to "chunked", then _there are no chunks..._

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm expecting - I'd just like to "see" it literally. ie be able to run a script against an endpoint that has `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and get multiple chunks, and against an endpoint that has `Content-Length:XXX` and get a single chunk.

Comment: You're going to probably want to do some coding for this. What languages are you familiar with?

Comment: It seems to me that there should be some tool out there that does this already, preferably a command line tool. I guess I can code it if need be, but I'd think curl would be able to do it, though I tried a few switches, `--raw` and `-N` that sounded relevant, but they didnt work.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/most-straightforward-way-of-getting-a-raw-unparsed-https-response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org) underlies Wireshark and other similar utilities and has a command line interface that might accomplish what you want. A command similar to:

`tcpdump -A -i en0 src XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA and port 80`

Would dump to the console all the raw packets from `XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA` port `80` that pass through `en0`. You could eliminate the `-i en0` for any interface and the expression is quite configurable.

You can find a few nice examples [tecmint.com](https://www.tecmint.com/12-tcpdump-commands-a-network-sniffer-tool/) and [danielmiessler.com](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/).

While you can save the entire capture with this solution, it does not save the chunks in different files as you requested. You would have to post-process the dump file to get that.

[Clarification] You would run `curl` in a separate terminal at the same time you were capturing packets.

[Addition] There is also a discussion of [Wireshark and http chunking](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/49128/why-chunked-http-response-is-not-decoded) that might be useful. And this [Reassemble pcap traces to recover http level data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210844/reassemble-pcap-traces-to-recover-http-level-data) question has an accepted solution to re-parsing the captures using [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a utility such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/),
which is usually a standard package on Linux.

Wireshark allows the deep inspection of messages and protocols
on all TCP/IP protocol levels
and supplies many sophisticated tools.

You can with Wireshark display the message byte-stream or go to
the protocol level and display higher levels of abstraction.

The part you are interested in is called
[Packet Reassembly](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvReassemblySection.html),
described as :

> Network protocols often need to transport large chunks of data which
>   are complete in themselves, e.g. when transferring a file. The
>   underlying protocol might not be able to handle that chunk size (e.g.
>   limitation of the network packet size), or is stream-based like TCP,
>   which doesn’t know data chunks at all.
>
> In that case the network protocol has to handle the chunk boundaries
>   itself and (if required) spread the data over multiple packets. It
>   obviously also needs a mechanism to determine the chunk boundaries on
>   the receiving side.
>
> Wireshark calls this mechanism reassembly, although a specific
>   protocol specification might use a different term for this (e.g.
>   desegmentation, defragmentation, etc).
>
> Reassembly might take place at several protocol layers, so it’s possible that multiple tabs in the “Packet Bytes” pane appear.

Once you can see the chunks you may also export them.

Here is an example of the “Packet Bytes” pane with a reassembled tab :

[image]

Comment: Why would anyone downvote a sophisticated utility such as Wireshark. preferring to do raw byte-dump by tcpdump that requires knowing the very fine points of the protocol to extract the chunks? Go figure.